# Cannot make the CSS button clickable

Tags: html, css

That's my first try:

```css
.pricingTable-firstTable_table__getstart {
  color: white;
  background-color: #71ce73;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 0px 0px #66ac64;
  letter-spacing: 0.07em;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricingTable-firstTable_table__getstart" href="https://website.com">JOIN</div>
```

It doesn't click, and doesn't change anything, I appreciate the help

Comment: You want the `div` on clicking to go to the `href` you specified?

Comment: you need to use an [anchor tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: @Martin, correct, Im not a devoloper but I get the logic, :)

Comment: @Pete I dont want a hyperlink, it ruins the button

Comment: You should use the correct elements and learn how to style them properly - add `display:inline-block` to your styles

Comment: Anchor tags lets you rightclick to open a new tab. All browsers interpret the anchor as a start of navigation. And much more. You should only use buttons for operations like: delete, edit, cancel and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to achieve this is wrapping your `div` inside an `a` tag:

```
<a href="https://website.com">
    <div class="pricingTable-firstTable_table__getstart">JOIN</div>
</a>
```

You could also solve this (less elegantly imo) using an onclick event in JavaScript:

```
<div class="pricingTable-firstTable_table__getstart" onclick="window.location.href='https://website.com';">JOIN</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an anchor link to look like a button. Style it something like this:

Css

```
.link-button {
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.link-button:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

And the markup

```
<a class="link-button">Anchor as button</a>
```

But I prefer to use buttons for operations, and show navigation as anchors. Because people recognize them for that.